# Exclude inactived functions from DifferentiationOptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, options, undocumented, system

The list of functions provided in `SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions"]` show which symbols will not be touched by `D`.  For example

```
D[x > y, x]
```

returns unevaluated.

However, I also need the same behavior when these functions are in their `Inactive` form:

```
D[Inactive[Greater][x,y],x]
```

unfortunately evaluates to `Derivative[1,0][Inactive[Greater]][x,y]`.  Rather I need it to be unevaluated.

How do I change the `SystemOptions` so that inactive forms are also untouched.

Supplying option `NonConstants->Greater` to `D` is inadequate because then I get the funny behavior that now `D[Less[a,b],x,NonConstants->Greater]` no longer evaluates to 0.

Comment: does this work: `excludedfuncs = 
  "ExcludedFunctions" /. ("DifferentiationOptions" /. 
     SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"]);
SetSystemOptions[
 "DifferentiationOptions" -> {"ExcludedFunctions" -> 
    Append[excludedfuncs, Inactivate]}]`?

Comment: @kglr no, it doesn't work.  Did it work for you?

Comment: Do you really need it to remain unevaluated, or do you need it to evaluate to something like `Inactive[Greater][1, 0]`?

Answer (score 5):

Since `Derivative` isn't protected, I would suggest adding a definition that transforms the undesired output a little further:

```
Derivative[1, 0][Inactive[Greater]][x_, y_] := Inactive[Greater][x, y]
```

The right-hand side can be adjusted depending on what you want. You could also add definitions that work for the other variable slot, but that wasn't asked for in the question.

With the above, you get the output

```
D[Inactive[Greater][x, y], x] // FullForm
```

> `Inactive[Greater][x, y]`

**Edit:**

Generalizing to more complex arguments, you could do the following:

```
Unprotect[D];
HoldPattern[D[Inactive[Greater][f_, g_], x_]] :=  Inactive[Greater][f, g];
Protect[D];
```

Then you get the extpected result:

```
D[Inactive[Greater][a x, y], x] // FullForm
```

> `Inactive[Greater][Times[a, x], y]`

Comment: There is the strange problem that `D[Inactive[Greater][a x, y], x]` leads to a factor of `a` as a coefficient.  Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: That's right, it's the chain rule. I addressed this in [another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27393/245), but to add it here would be more difficult... In this case you may have to add the definition to `D` but this requires unprotecting it first, which may be too far from what you're willing to do.