# Can Mathematica do this derivative?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The definition of the elasticity (used in economics a lot) of a function f(x) is $\frac{\mathrm{d} \log(f(x))}{\mathrm{d} \log(x)}$. Using the chain rule, it is easy to show that:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \log(f(x))}{\mathrm{d} \log(x)}
=\frac{\mathrm{d}\log(f(x))}{\mathrm{d}f(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\log(x))}
=\frac{x}{f(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}
$$

I couldn't find a way to input the derivative directly into Mathematica though. Is there a way?

```
Dt[ Log[ f[x] ], Log[x] ]
```

almost works, but not quite.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27393/4999

Comment: A somewhat more direct coding of the formula works: `Dt[Log[f[x]]]/Dt[Log[x]]`.

Comment: That is an excellent tip Michael E2. Thank you very much.

Comment: `In[1804]:= D[Log[f[Exp[y]]], y] /. y -> Log[x]

Out[1804]= (x Derivative[1][f][x])/f[x]` also handles this.

Comment: This also works: `Dt[Log[f[x]], Log[x]] /. x -> E^Hold[Log[x]] // ReleaseHold ` .

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) ["ChainD"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ChainD) for this purpose:

```
ResourceFunction["ChainD"][Log[f[x]],Log[x]]
```

> (x f'[x])/f[x]

Comment: Thanks. Had not come across that (experimental) function before. Looks like there are lots of interesting things to play around with using it.